# The phrase - "I remain sceptical" vs "I continue to remain sceptical"

Tags: expressions, archaicisms, redundancy, pragmatics

> During a parent meeting , I heard a teacher say :
>
> - **I remain sceptical** (on the progress of the child).
>
> and the parent questioning him-
>
> - Why do you **continue to remain sceptical**?

- Isn't "I am sceptical" a better phrasing  instead of "I remain
  sceptical" or is it informal?
- continue to remain sceptical- makes sense to me, because the
  sceptism is based on the past performance which was poor and no improvement is apparent. Does my logic meets the grammar?

Comment: You remain sceptical if you doubt something about which you were sceptical in the first place. You *continue* to remain sceptical if, at a later time, you still doubt it.

Comment: what confuses me is that "remain' carries a connotation of "continuity", so why continue to remain.

Comment: Apparently you remain confused about this. Which just means that you were confused at some time in the past, and now you continue to be confused.

Comment: _Remain_ is a very troublesome verb, especially [in constructions like _She remains to be convinced_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/remaindershandout.pdf). In the sentences in the OQ, it simply means a continuative sense of auxiliary _be_ with a stative predicate adjective _skeptical_. That's in the first one. In the second one it indicates that this is a long- and firmly-held position, which is not implied without _remain_.

Comment: While logically challenging, it might be just a way of expressing polite incredulity on the part of the parent.

Comment: @JohnLawler, thank you for the link. I had this notion that 'continue to remain' is tautalogical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I remain skeptical" implies that I was skeptical in the past and I still am skeptical, despite implied events that might have caused me to no longer be skeptical.

"I am skeptical" refers only to the present time and carries no implied information about my skepticism in the past, or any events that might have changed it.

"continue to remain skeptical" is a bit of a tautology. "Continue to be skeptical" and "remain skeptical" mean the same thing. However "continue to remain" is fairly common usage.

Comment: “Why do you still keep on continuing to stay persistent in carrying on remaining sceptical?”